# Change image when tab changes HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I'm currently doing a website and I can't seem to work out how to get the image marked myImage to change when you click a different tab.

here's my code. Any help would be appreciated, I haven't coded in HTML for ages.

```html
<div class="media-container-row mt-5 pt-3">
            <div class="mbr-figure" style="width: 50%;">
                <img id="myImage" src="assets/images/image1.jpg" alt=Security" title="">
            </div>
            <div class="tabs-container">
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link mbr-fonts-style active show display-7" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#tabs4-7_tab0" aria-selected="true">
                            Door Supervisors</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link mbr-fonts-style active show display-7" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#tabs4-7_tab1" aria-selected="true">Manned Guarding</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link mbr-fonts-style active show display-7" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#tabs4-7_tab2" aria-selected="true">Close Protection</a></li>
                    
                    
                    
                </ul>
                <div class="tab-content">
                    <div id="tab1" class="tab-pane in active" role="tabpanel">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <p class="mbr-text py-5 mbr-fonts-style display-7">
                                    Security offers bespoke packages for Door Supervisors. Our Door Supervisors are professional, delivering to your customers great service by being friendly and allowing you to have piece of mind when it comes to your venue.&nbsp;</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="tab2" class="tab-pane" role="tabpanel">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <p class="mbr-text py-5 mbr-fonts-style display-7"> Security can also offer Manned Security to your premises. Manned Guards being brilliant deterrents to Tresspassers, Thieves and other threats to your premises or land.</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: You can't do this in pure HTML. Do you use javascript? With a framework like jQuery perhaps?

Comment: @Multicolaure currently using bootstrap JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily do this using JS or jQuery. I would do something like this:

```
<img id="myImage" src="IMG_0680.JPG">
<div onclick="document.getElementById('myImage').src='IMG_0680.JPG'">TAB_ONE</div>
<div onclick="document.getElementById('myImage').src='IMG_0681.JPG'">TAB_TWO</div>
```

Here is the link to an example:
https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_intro_lightbulb

Hope it helps, good luck!

Comment: Thanks so much! This worked perfectly with a bit of working out where to shove it lmao

Answer (score 0):

You can do the below way.

- Assign [data attributes](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp) e.g. `data-url` to nav items and later get the value of the attribute to change the image source dynamically
- Get All Elements which has class `nav-item` and bind a function to it which triggers on clicking
- In the event, change the image url by getting the `data-url` attribute

```js
window.onload = function()
{
  var navItems = document.getElementsByClassName("nav-item");
  var imageChangeFunction = function() 
  {
    var attribute = this.getAttribute("data-url");
    
      console.log(attribute);
    var image = document.getElementById("myImage");
    image.src = attribute;
    image.title = attribute;
    image.alt = attribute;
};

for (var i = 0; i < navItems.length; i++) {
    navItems[i].addEventListener('click', imageChangeFunction, false);
}
}
```

```html
<div class="media-container-row mt-5 pt-3">
            <div class="mbr-figure" style="width: 50%;">
                <img id="myImage" src="assets/images/image1.jpg" alt=Security" title="">
            </div>
            <div class="tabs-container">
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
                    <li class="nav-item" data-url="Image 1 Url goes here"><a class="nav-link mbr-fonts-style active show display-7" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#tabs4-7_tab0" aria-selected="true">
                            Door Supervisors</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item" data-url="Image 2 Url goes here"><a class="nav-link mbr-fonts-style active show display-7" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#tabs4-7_tab1" aria-selected="true">Manned Guarding</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item" data-url="Image 3 Url goes here"><a class="nav-link mbr-fonts-style active show display-7" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#tabs4-7_tab2" aria-selected="true">Close Protection</a></li>
                    
                    
                    
                </ul>
                <div class="tab-content">
                    <div id="tab1" class="tab-pane in active" role="tabpanel">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <p class="mbr-text py-5 mbr-fonts-style display-7">
                                    Security offers bespoke packages for Door Supervisors. Our Door Supervisors are professional, delivering to your customers great service by being friendly and allowing you to have piece of mind when it comes to your venue.&nbsp;</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="tab2" class="tab-pane" role="tabpanel">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <p class="mbr-text py-5 mbr-fonts-style display-7"> Security can also offer Manned Security to your premises. Manned Guards being brilliant deterrents to Tresspassers, Thieves and other threats to your premises or land.</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```